How do you use a SwiftData inverse relationship with a @Bindable
I have an inverse relationship between workout and Exercise like so:
@Model
class Workout: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String

    var exercises: [Exercise]?
    
    var startTime: Date
    var endTime: Date

@Model
class Exercise: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var exerciseName: ExerciseName
    var sets: [ExerciseSet]?
    var date: Date
    @Relationship(inverse: \Workout.exercises) var workout: Workout

Then I create a Workout an insert it into modelContext before navigating to editWorkoutView:
 Button {
                let workout = Workout(id: UUID())
                modelContext.insert(workout)
                path.append(workout)
                        
               }

in EditWorkoutView I accept the workout as a Bindable then pass that Bindable onto the view that the Sheet presents:
struct EditWorkoutView: View {
    @Bindable var workout: Workout      //SwiftData will update all this on its own as soon as you bind this to a TextField
    @State private var showExercieSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Workout Details")) {
                    TextField("Enter workout name",text: $workout.name)
                    DatePicker("Start Time", selection: $workout.startTime)
                    DatePicker("End Time", selection: $workout.endTime)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Exercises")) {
                    if let exercises =  workout.exercises {
                        ForEach(exercises){ exercise in
                            VStack {
                                Text("\(exercise.exerciseName)")
                            }
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: delete)
                    } else {
                        Text("No Exericses Yet")
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    Button {
                        showExercieSheet = true
                        
                    } label: {
                        Text("Add Exercise")
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showExercieSheet) {
            AddExerciseView(workout: workout)
                .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
            
        }

in AddExerciseView I insert an Exercise to modelContext:
@Bindable var workout: Workout

 
    Button {
        //check If selection isnt empty than create an Exercise with this(selection) as the ExerciseName
        //and dismiss this sheet
        if(selection != nil) {
            let newExercise = Exercise(id: UUID(),exerciseName: selection!, date: Date.now, workout: workout)
            
            modelContext.insert(newExercise)

            //Uncommenting this causes the error: Unsupported relationship key path ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Exercise, Workout>
            //workout.exercises?.append(newExercise)
           
            dismiss()
        }
        
    }

Now the problem is I can only see the new exercise in the workouts list when I restart the app they aren't being reflected as soon as an exercise is add and I don't understand why because I was told swiftData would take care of everything manually if you use @Bindbale?
//Note this works if I remove the inverse relation and both update it in workout.exericses and add it to Exercise model context but Im curious how to get it working while keeping the inverse relationship

Unrelated but you can do if let selection { ... instead and you will get the nil check and unwrapping of the optional in one go.

Thank you I will implement that it also removes the need to force unwrap it below that

I don't think this has anything to do with @Bindable but instead this is an issue with SwiftUI/SwiftData where the view doesn't get notified about any updates when you change a relationship and/or a related object. In EditWorkoutView it works fine because here you are working directly with the Workout object. I believe there should be similar questions here where this has been discussed.
